How to create a sticky header and reversed message order in Jetpack Compose LazyColumn?
I am working on a chat app using Jetpack Compose and trying to implement the following:

Sticky Header: I want to display a sticky header at the top of the LazyColumn, which contains information like "End-to-End Encryption Enabled". It should be scrolled with lazycolumn.
Reversed Message Order: The messages should appear in reverse order (i.e., the most recent message should be at the bottom).
Message Layout: The header should remain at the top regardless of scrolling, and the messages below it should behave like a regular chat with reversed layout.

Here’s the code that I have so far:
@Composable
fun SecureChatApp() {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // Header with End-to-End Encryption status

        // LazyColumn for messages, reversed layout
        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            reverseLayout = true // Reverses the order of items in the list
        ) {

            repeat(10) {

                item {
                    Text("Message ${it}")

                }

            }

            item {
                Row{
                    Text("End to End Enabled for this chat")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

What I've Tried:

I've used reverseLayout = true to make the messages appear in reverse order.
The sticky header is placed before the LazyColumn, but I'm unsure if this is the correct approach for keeping the header fixed while reversing the message list.

Problem:

I want the header to always stay at the top, regardless of the number of messages.
The messages should be reversed, so the most recent one appears at the bottom.

Desired Outcome:
I want to ensure that:

The header stays at the top and scrolled with messages.
The messages are reversed with the latest message appearing at the bottom when there are multiple messages.

Can anyone help me achieve this layout with LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?

Wrap LazyColumn inside Box and add Header composable with Top alignment
@Composable
fun SecureChatApp() {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // LazyColumn for messages
        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = 48.dp), // Leave space for sticky header
            reverseLayout = true // Reverse order of items
        ) {
            // Messages
            items(100) { index ->
                Text(
                    text = "Message ${index + 1}",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .background(Color.LightGray),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
                )
            }
        }

        // Sticky Header
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(48.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter) // Always positioned at the top
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "End-to-End Encryption Enabled",
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}


It is not working. When i have 2 messages the header is not top. It shows before first message in reverse layout. Also,   stickyHeader should be placed after messages to show correctly on top because reverselayout=true.

Oh yaa, then you should consider using Box composable. Checkout the updated answer!

Please read my question carefully, i need to scroll header along with messages not sticky.

Maybe you want something like this?
Set the scroll state to the last element, instead of using reverseLayout
val items = List(10) { it }
val state = rememberLazyListState()

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    state.scrollToItem(items.lastIndex)
}

LazyColumn(
    state = state
) {
    stickyHeader {
        Text("End to End Enabled for this chat")
    }
    items(items) {
        ListItem(
            headlineContent = {
                Text("Item $it")
            }
        )
    }
}

